# Nesting "for" Loop n Times

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm writing a program that finds passwords. I ran into a problem when I saw that the "for" loops to replace parts of the password would have to be repeated for the variable of the chosen password length. The goal of this program is to generate and check a password of any character array, starting with "0" and going through "? (n times)", where '0' is the first character and '?' is the last character.

**Is there any way to repeat a for loop a variable number of times *without* coding them in individually?**

Note, based on well-received comments:
The "repeat a for loop" is probably more correctly expressed as "nest several for loops".

```
int maxLength = 32; //Length of the password, changes via input
char output[maxLength] = "";
for (int currentLength = 1; currentLength < maxLength + 1; currentLength++) {
    for (int characterNumber = 0; characterNumber < 96 /*characters found with switch/case, 95 total*/; characterNumber++) {
        for (int position = currentLength /*position in string*/; position > 0; position--) {
            //For loops of character and position currentLength times
            char newCharacter = '\0'; //Avoiding not initialized error, could be and character
            output[position - 1] = getChar(characterNumber, newCharacter);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of an output would be:
...01, 02, 03..., 10, 11..., a0, a1..., ????4afuh7yfzdn_)aj901...

Comment: wrap a while around your for loop

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: @LioraHaydont There's nothing wrong with the code (as far as I know, this is just a rough rewrite of it), the problem is that it's not finished, as I commented in where the unfinished code would go. I'm not sure how to do this otherwise.

Comment: you can get the effect of n-deep for loops with recursion

Comment: Just have a running number and convert it to base-96 (or whatever alphabet size you have). No need in recursion or nested loops.

Comment: You do realize that even passwords of only 10 characters, this program will run for *centuries*?.

Comment: ... and if the password checker is worth its salt, it won't accept a password more frequently than ... once per second?

Comment: My "centuries" estimate is based on a billion per second, but you're right, any real password system would be using PBKDF2 or something that takes time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do not need to repeat the for loop. Instead you need to nest it.
The most inviting solution to implement this is a recursive construct.

Pseudo code:

```
void nestloop(int depth, int width)
{
    if(depth>0)
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            nestloop(depth-1, width);
        }
    } else
    {
        /* do whatever you need done inside the innermost loop */
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, so I'll try it and report back with a best answer when I'm done. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may accept the answer; Recursion is the solution for nested loops where the depth of nesting isn't known in advance.

Comment: Recursion should be considered very carefully. It's very easy to overflow the stack.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I agree. But this kind, with a static, predetermined, directly selected depth, is probably the most harmless imaginable kind. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without recursion by using an array to hold the loop counter values. When an outer loop counter is incremented, the inner loop counters need to be reinitialized. A counter index keeps track of which loop counter is being initialized or incremented.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_something(const int loopcount[], size_t nloops)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < nloops; i++)
    {
        printf("%d%s", loopcount[i], i + 1 < nloops ? ", " : ";\n");
    }
}

#define NLOOPS  2
#define LSTART  0
#define LSTEP   1
#define LLIMIT  3

int main(void)
{
    int loopcount[NLOOPS];
    int countidx;

    countidx = -1;
    do {
        if (++countidx < NLOOPS) {
            /* Reinitialize inner loop counters. */
            loopcount[countidx] = LSTART;
        } else {
            /* Do something with the loop counter values. */
            do_something(loopcount, NLOOPS);
            /* Increment the loop counters. */
            while (countidx-- > 0 &&
                   (loopcount[countidx] += LSTEP) >= LLIMIT)
                ;
        }
    } while (countidx >= 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I assumed `LSTART < LLIMIT` and `LSTEP > 0` are both true, but it is easy to reverse the test conditions if `LSTEP < 0` is true, and it is easy to change the `else` to an `else if` if `LSTART` is already at or beyond `LLIMIT`.

Output:

```
0, 0;
0, 1;
0, 2;
1, 0;
1, 1;
1, 2;
2, 0;
2, 1;
2, 2;
```