# Can i generate "loop" in run time base on user input?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, runtime

Hi so I am wondering is there any way to create a certain amount of for loops during runtime base on the user input?

So lets say if i want to make a program that can prints out all the combinations of choices (base on the user input) of a multiple choice exam (each questions has four choices such as: A,B,C,D)

How can I achieve that ? 
(The following fucntion I made can sort of achive that ,but all the for loops are pre-build (Totol is 15) and I wish to see some way to generate loops at run time.)

For Example:

```
cout<<"Enter how many questions in the exam?"

cin>>n;  // if n is 20

cout<<"Here is all the possible combination..."
//gerateing 20 loop...

void print(char arr[],int s)
{
  int c=0;

    for(int x=0;x<s;x++)
    {
        cout<<arr[x];

        for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i];

            for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
            {
                cout<<arr[i];

                for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                {
                    cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                    for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                    {
                        cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                        for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                        {
                           cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                            for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                            {
                                cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                                for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                {
                                    cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                                        for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                        {
                                            cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                                            for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                            {
                                                cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                                                for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                                {
                                                    cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                                                    for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                                    {
                                                       cout<<arr[j]; c++;
                                                        for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                                        {
                                                            cout<<arr[j]; c++;
                                                            for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                                            {
                                                                cout<<arr[j]; c++;

                                                                for(int j=0;j<s;j++)
                                                                    {
                                                                        cout<<arr[j];
                                                                        c++;
                                                                    }

                                                            }


                                                        }


                                                    }


                                                }


                                            }


                                        }


                                }


                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }
         cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"TOTAL combinations (if there are 15 questions):"<<c<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: whoops, in the above code , i should only increase  c  in the last for loop haha

Comment: Have a look here, it is C but the concept is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265552/nesting-for-loop-n-times/49265629#49265629

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you ask for. It will print in every loop the same array, so you will get s*s*s...*s (as many s as no of loops) and they wont be in order. You have 2 options if A is an answer. 2 options if B is an answer. Same C and D. So there are 16 possible answers from one question. Generate all of them. And than mix all of them for every question.

Comment: My code assums there are 15 questions , so the total combination is 1073741824 (4 to the power of 15) ,  for making the"16 possible answer" the one u are talking about will need 2 for loops (4 to the pwoer of 2) . and my question was how to make loop at run time

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you learn about recursive functions (functions that call themselves within their code) this will allow you to write the code required for each question to determine each possible question from that point in the tree of questions without having a new loop for every step in the tree. The function just needs an if statement which determines if the maximum number of questions has been reached otherwise it will go on infinitely. I found it a bit tricky to learn recursion at first but it’s very powerful with many use cases. Just search “recursive functions” and you will likely find many helpful sources

Comment: Great idea , but even I can get the number of combinations though recurtion , but how about printting out each chocies , how to set all the condictions for the problem i have ? and plus recursion will cause overflow if I  want to make  total "1073741824 recursive calls" which is the total from the above code lol

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition   it's not hard.. assure yourself

Comment: Perhaps every time the depth limit is reached print a copy of a temporary array holding the current ‘state’ the program is up to, the array would have to be global. Since the depth is not 1073741824 I don’t imagine it would cause an overflow. I’m a python programmer myself but I’m sure there will be a way.

Comment: getting this error  :RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object , anyway.. appreciate your answer